# Is there a way to view the shape of tensor in graph execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am somewhat new to tensorflow and I am dealing with a model which gets different batch sizes. This is the dataset loaded from a generator with the shapes given. the batch size varies for every Iteration

```
logo_hash_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(presentationTrainData2,output_types=(tf.float32,tf.float32,tf.float32),
                                                  output_shapes=((None,12,2048),(None,6,1131),(None,10,300)))
```

This is the loss function of the model

```
def p_h_loss_fn(modal_i,modal_a,modal_t):
    loss = 0
    times = modal_i.shape[0]
    for i in range(times):
#         print(modal_i.shape,modal_i[i].shape)
#         this prints None in graph execution and batch size in eager execution
        example = tf.broadcast_to(tf.reshape(modal_i[i],[1,-1]),modal_i.shape)
        loss = loss + tf.keras.metrics.mean_squared_error(example,modal_i) + \
                tf.keras.metrics.mean_squared_error(example,modal_t) + \
                tf.keras.metrics.mean_squared_error(example,modal_a)
    loss = lamb*loss
    return loss
```

The loss function requires the shape (more importantly the batch size, which differs) of model output. Suppose the output tensor shape is (25,x,y) where x,y are some constant integers. If I use tf.function the shape of output is (None,x,y) but in eager execution it gives the required shape of (25,x,y). I know that graph execution is different from eager execution.I think this is because  I am sending the inputs as (None,x,y), but is there any way to get the shape of tensor in graph execution

```
@tf.function
def train_presentation_model():
    for j,(i_data,a_data,t_data) in enumerate(logo_hash_data):

        with tf.GradientTape(persistent = True) as tape:
            modal_i,modal_a,modal_t = logo(i_data,a_data,t_data)
            loss = p_h_loss_fn(modal_i,modal_a,modal_t)
        
        total_loss += tf.cast(loss[0],tf.float32)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss,logo.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads,logo.trainable_variables))
        del tape
    p_loss.append(total_loss)
    print('the loss of model Epoch[%d / %d]: is %.4f , time: %d s' % (epoch, p_epochs, total_loss,
                                                                      time.time() - begin_time))
```

this the error if the code is run in graph execution

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20248/790870176.py in <module>
      1 for i in range(1):
      2     print('Epoch' + str(i+1))
----> 3     train_presentation_model(p_epochs)
      4 #     train_tagging_model(t_epochs)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151     except Exception as e:
    152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154     finally:
    155       del filtered_tb

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1130             else:
   1131               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20248/1697794745.py", line 23, in train_presentation_model  *
        for j,(i_data,a_data,t_data) in enumerate(logo_hash_data):
    File "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20248/3069989111.py", line 5, in p_h_loss_fn  *
        for i in range(times):

    TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This is not the entire code. If it is not sufficient I can give more information

I am getting the same error even if I used tf.shape(modal_i)[0]

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151     except Exception as e:
    152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154     finally:
    155       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1130             else:
   1131               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-29-ab0d42b76775>", line 27, in train_presentation_model  *
        loss = p_h_loss_fn(modal_i,modal_a,modal_t)
    File "<ipython-input-22-f924fc489bfd>", line 4, in p_h_loss_fn  *
        times = tf.shape(modal_i.shape)[0]

    ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape (None, 150) to a Tensor.
```

Comment: To know the shape of the Tensor you can use `tf.Tensor.shape`. If you have ragged Tensors and trying to reshape, which is not possible. First convert ragged tensors to tensors and then apply reshape. For more information on the library visit this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#get_shape). Thanks!